# Existence of a viscosity solution

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, parabolic-pde

**Setup**
I'm trying to find sufficient conditions for the existence of a viscosity solution to the following PDE,
$$
f(t,s,z) + \partial_sf(t,s,z) \\
+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left[
\partial_{z_i} f(t,s,z)a_i(t,s,z)\right] 
+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left[
\partial_{z_i}\partial_{z_j} f(t,s,z)m_{i,j}(t,s,z)\right]\\
-
\left(
\sum_{i,j =1}^{\infty} \partial_{z_i}f(t,s,z) g(\int_0^T \partial_{z_i}f(t,s,z) ds)
\right)=0
$$
on the finite interval $[0,T]$, where $a_i$, $m_{i,j}$ need not be continuous, $g$ if infinitely-differentiable and strictly convex on $[0,T]$ and $f(t,s,z)$ is short hand for $f(t,s,z_1,z_2,z_3,....)$.

**Question**
My question is, what are some sufficiently general assumptions on $a_i$, $m_i$ and $g$ to assure that there exists a (preferably unique) viscosity solution, almost everywhere on $[0,T]\times [0,T]\times \ell^2$?

**So Far**
So far I have shown that if I assume the highly restrictive case that $g(x)=x$ and $a_i$ and $m_i$ are linear then this is a semi-linear PDE so I have existence of a mild solution.  Of-course I would like to have significantly more general assumptions than these.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come to this PDE? (also, I assume $\partial_s$ should be $\partial_s f$)

Comment: It came up in some research, why have you encountered it also?

Comment: I have not; I was just curious. Sometimes (though not always, or even often) having intuition into the origins of the problem helps.

Comment: @AIM_BLB It is really curious to see a PDE with *infinitely many* independent variables. Could you shine a little bit more light on the background?

Comment: It comes from a problem in SPDEs.